# Redirect users to the login if they are not authenticated and to the homepage if authenticated when accessing a url that they should not have access

Tags: laravel

After a user creates a conference he is redirected to a page "http://proj.test/conference/manage/2" to manage that specific conference.

A user that creates a conference with id "2" for example should be allowed to access "http://proj.test/conference/manage/2". But only this user that created this conference with id "2" should be allowed to access this conference.

The other users if they access "http://proj.test/conference/manage/2" should be redirected to the login page if are not authenticated and to the homepage if they are authenticated.

I was trying to do this with the code below, particularly with the code in the manage method, but when the user is redirected to an url for example "http://proj.test/conference/manage/2" it appears always:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'conference.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `conferences` where `conferences`.`user_id` = 1 and `conferences`.`user_id` is not null and `conferences`.`id` = 7 limit 1)
```

The issue should be because in the conferences table I have a field "conference_creator_id" instead of "user_id". But it's not possible to maintain the "conference creator_id"? But also, I dont know if this approach in the manage method is ok for this context and if with this approach is possible to do that thing of redirect a user, that accesses "http://layout.test/conference/manage/2", and he didn't create this conference with id 2, to the login page if is not authenticated and redirect to the homepage if he is authenticated. Do you know a proper approach to do that?

**Store method:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'conference_name' => 'required|max:255|string',
         ...
    ]);
    $conference = Conference::create([
        'name' => $request->conference_name,
        ...
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('conference.manage', ['id' => $conference->id]);
}
```

**Manage method:**

```
public function manage($id){
    $conference = Auth::user()->conferences()->findOrFail($id);
    return view('conferences.manage')>with('myconference',$conferene);
}
```

**Routes:**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function(){

    Route::post('/conference/store', [
        'uses' => 'ConferenceController@store',
        'as'   => 'conference.store'
    ]);
    Route::get('/conference/create', [
        'uses' => 'ConferenceController@create',
        'as'   => 'conference.create'
    ]);
    Route::get('conference/manage/{id}', [ 'uses' => 'ConferenceController@manage', 'as'=>'conference.manage']);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the custom foreign key to the `conferences` relationship definition:

```
public function conferences()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Conference::class, 'conference_creator_id');
}
```

But it's better to follow Laravel [naming conventions](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions) described in my repo and change the column name to `user_id`.

And you need to use [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#generating-policies) for authorization purposes.

Comment: Thanks now the error doesn't appear. But for example, if a user creates a conference with id "2" he can access "http://proj.test/event/manage/2". But the other users cant access this url and if they are authenticated should be redirected to the homepage. But this part is not working, when a user that didn't create the conference with id "2" accesses  "http://proj.test/event/manage/2".and is authenticated the url remains "http://proj.test/event/manage/2" and it appears: "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found." Do you know why?

Comment: @JohnZ it's not related to the existing code. You need to use [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#generating-policies) for that

Answer (score 0):

A simple way will be to check the `id` of the current user

```
public function __construct()
{
    //User should be logged in before accessing the `manage` method
    $this->middleware('auth')->only(['manage']);
}

public function manage(Conference $conference){

    //Redirect the user to the homepage when its ID is different of the ID of the user who created the conference
    if ($conference->user_id != Auth::id()){
        return redirect(url('/'));
    }

    return view('conferences.manage')>with('myconference',$conferene);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but with that solution even the user that created the conference cant access "proj.test/event/manage/2". All users are being redirected to the homepage.

Comment: Thanks, but it appears the same issue when a user that didn't create the conference with id 2 accesses "proj.test/event/manage/2" appears:"Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

Answer (score 0):

You could add to your controller class:

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

This way it'll check whether the user is signed in or as a guest and deal with them accordingly depending on the result.

The alternative would be to wrap a Route group around anything that required 'auth' (as my answer states in your previous question).